# How to store a value from a database as a variable to use in an insert statement

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

With a dropdown box and a button I am trying to insert PharmacyId into an order table however I don't know how to store the pharmacyid as a variable to read it in like the other values I am getting. I have stored the rest as sessions like so:

```
Protected Sub btnconfirm_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnconfirm.Click

        ' Dropdown for pharmacy  someVariable = DropPharm.SelectedItem.Value  


        Dim PatientId As Integer = Session("PatientId")
        Dim DoctorId As Integer = Session("DoctorId")
        Dim PharmacyId As Integer ' pharmacy must be stored(DropPharm.SelectedValue  must be the selected value)
        Dim MedicineId As Integer = Session("MedicineId")
        Dim DateOrdered As Date


         ' How to get pharmacy id stored

               'select pharmacy_id from Pharmacy where Pharmname = '';  ??


        Dim query As String = String.Empty
        query &= "INSERT INTO Order_pres (PatientId, PharmacyId, MedicineId, "
        query &= "                     DoctorId, Dateordered)  "
        query &= "VALUES (@PatientId, @MedicineId, @PharmacyId, @DoctorId, @DateOrdered)"



        Dim sqlCs As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SurgeryConnectionString").ConnectionString

        Using conn As New SqlConnection(sqlCs),
              comm As New SqlCommand(query, conn)
            With comm.Parameters



                .Add("@PatientId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session("PatientId")
                .Add("@DoctorId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session("DoctorId")
                .Add("@MedicineId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session("MedicineId")
                .Add("@PharmacyId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session("PharmacyId")
                .Add("@DateOrdered", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(DateOrdered)



            End With


            Try
                conn.Open()
                Dim rowInserted = comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                If rowInserted = 1 Then
                    lblconfirm.Text = "Order Placed"
                Else
                    lblnoconfirm.Text = "Order not placed"
                End If
            Catch ex As SqlException
                lblnoconfirm.Text = "Unexpectd error: " & ex.Message
            End Try

        End Using
```

The pharmacyId appears on the .aspx page with this dropdown and sql data source:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlPharm" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SurgeryConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT PharmacyId, Pharmname FROM Pharmacy "></asp:SqlDataSource>



<asp:DropDownList ID="DropPharm" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlPharm" DataTextField="Pharmname" DataValueField="PharmacyId"></asp:DropDownList>
```

When a value is selected from the dropdown and the button is clicked I have it appearing on a label at the moment, I am just trying to get it saved as a variable so it can be read into the insery query

[image]

Hopefully someone can help, thank you

Comment: What is the Error you are getting. Or you want to know how to insert the value

Comment: I want to know how to insert the value, it needs to be stored as a variable - the rest have values as sessions, this cannot be done for pharmacy Id - first there has to be a select statement  i.e:  `'select pharmacy_id from Pharmacy where Pharmname = '';  ??`   then a new connection string but I don't know how to do this

Comment: you can simply replace `.Add("@PharmacyId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session("PharmacyId")` to .`Add("@PharmacyId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(DropPharm.selectedvalue)` and let me know

Comment: the error that was coming up before I used this code was ` 
Unexpectd error: The parameterized query '(@PatientId int,@DoctorId int,@MedicineId int,@PharmacyId int,@D' expects the parameter '@PharmacyId', which was not supplied. `

Comment: the error I am getting now is

Comment: Unexpectd error: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "fk_to_pharmacyid". The conflict occurred in database "E:\FINAL_PROJ (2) (1)\FINAL_PROJ (4) (1)\FINAL_PROJ (4) (1)\FINAL_PROJ\APP_DATA\SURGERYDB.MDF", table "dbo.Pharmacy", column 'PharmacyId'. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: are you using Team viewer give me id and password

Comment: I have a foreign key set up - pharmacyId from the pharmacy table is in the order table like the other Ids - medicineId, patientId etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115943/discussion-between-a-goutam-and-laurajs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to  pass your value in correct sequence

```
Dim query As String = String.Empty
        query &= "INSERT INTO Order_pres (PatientId, PharmacyId, MedicineId, "
        query &= "                     DoctorId, Dateordered)  "
        query &= "VALUES (@PatientId, @MedicineId, @PharmacyId, @DoctorId, @DateOrdered)"
```

Will be

```
Dim query As String = String.Empty
        query &= "INSERT INTO Order_pres (PatientId, PharmacyId, MedicineId, "
        query &= "                     DoctorId, Dateordered)  "
        query &= "VALUES (@PatientId,@PharmacyId, @MedicineId,  @DoctorId, @DateOrdered)"
```

This will resolve your problem